# Retrieve expired message from iot hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, dead-letter

I send messages C2D, it has a TTL of 90 seconds (default). I have almost 10k devices.
I want to know what all messages were not delivered and towards which device.

Do we have a concept like a dead letter queue with IOT hub, How can I implement this?

Comment: I do recommend to read the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-c2d, where is described in the details all c2d messaging process. You didn't describe your scenario for using c2d messaging over 10k devices, so please read also the following document about the c2d operation throttles https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling#quotas-and-throttling

Comment: Kamlesh if Roman's suggestions helped, can you let us know? I believe the comment above should be converted to the answer to this.